# ConTeXt: How to enforce spacing below a columnsetspan?

Tags: spacing, context, framed

I'm using columnsets with floating columnsetspans, and I would like to enforce a small amount of vertical space below a columnsetspan and the following text, *outside* the frame.

Here are some example style definitions:

```
\starttext
% Define columns.
\definecolumnset[standard][n=2, balance=yes]

% The shaded box with outline.
\startuniqueMPgraphic{shadebox}
    draw OverlayBox enlarged (0, -1mm) withcolor black withpen pensquare;
    fill OverlayBox enlarged (0, -1mm) withcolor transparent(1,.1,blue) ;
\stopuniqueMPgraphic
\defineoverlay[shadebox][\useMPgraphic{shadebox}]

% These column spans are shaded.
\definecolumnsetspan[wide][n=2, background=shadebox, indenting={small,yes,first}, offset=2mm]

\startcolumnset[standard]
\startcolumnsetspan[wide]
\input tufte
\stopcolumnsetspan

\input zapf
\stoptext
```

I'd like a "wide" columnsetspan (when arranged vertically above other text) to have a few millimeters of spacing below it to set it apart from the following text, regardless of how the span is positioned on the page. All of the `offset` parameters seem to affect inner spacing, and `after` is within the frame.

How can I ensure that there's sufficient space below this columnsetspan?